# How to combine two values from different rows and sum the result?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to combine two values from different rows and sum the count value associate with them

I have:

| Name | Number(count) |
| --- | --- |
| Paul | 50 |
| John | 50 |

i need

| Name | Number(count) |
| --- | --- |
| paul/john | 100 |

How can I make this work with in SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Two aggregates.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (name, count) as
  2    (select 'Paul', 50 from dual union all
  3     select 'John', 50 from dual
  4    )
```

Query:

```
  5  select listagg(name, '/') within group (order by null) name,
  6    sum(count) sum_count
  7  from test;

NAME                  SUM_COUNT
-------------------- ----------
Paul/John                   100

SQL>
```